# how to fill in the missing values using the previous and post values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, mean

If my data is:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'Array1':[None,1,2,None,3,None,4,5,6,None]})
```

I want to fill in the missing values so that the data is:

```
1,1,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,5,6,6
```

You can see that the first missing value is filled as 1 because the second value is 1, which is the closest value. And the last value is missing. I fill in 6 because the closest one is 6. Then, I use (2+3)/2=2.5 to fill in the fourth missing value, i.e., the mean of the previous and post values.

I do not know if Python has a function to do this? If so, could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `interpolate`

```
a.interpolate(method ='linear',limit_direction ='both')
Out[502]: 
   Array1
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     2.5
4     3.0
5     3.5
6     4.0
7     5.0
8     6.0
9     6.0
```